# Java - Parsing a text file with integers and strings

Tags: java

I have a text file with the following contents (delimiter is a single space):

```
1231 2134 143 wqfdfv -89 rwq f 8 qer q2
sl;akfj salfj 3 sl 123
```

My objective is to read the integers and strings seperately. Once I know how to parse them, I will create another output file to save them (but my question is only to know how to parse this text file).

I tried using Scanner and I am NOT able to get beyond the first inetger:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File ("a.txt")).useDelimiter("");
while (s.hasNext()){
System.out.print(s.nextInt());}
```

and the output is

```
1231
```

How can I also  get other integers from both the lines?

My desired outout is:

```
1231 
2134 
143
-89
8
3 
123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delimiter should be something else like at least one whitespace or more

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File ("a.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
        System.out.print(s.nextInt()); // display the found integer
    } else {
        s.next(); // else read the next token
    }
}
```

and i have to admit that the solution from gotuskar is the better one in this simple case.

Comment: can't reproduce. Maybe you are using the wrong locale? Try setting the locale with s.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); Is the - really a simple dash? or some funny character?

Answer (score 3):

When reading data from file, read all as string types. Then test whether it is number by parsing it using `Integer.parseInt()`. If it throws an exception then it is a string, otherwise it is a number.

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String str = s.next();
    try { 
        b = Integer.parseInt(str); 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // only catch specific exception
        // its a string, do what you need to do with it here
        continue;
    }
    // its a number
 }
```

Comment: I tried to use Integer.parseInt() and I am able to catch the exception but not sure how to go back to continue reading the file. see my edit above.